# Eclipse. different behaviour after run test manually and using "maven install"

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, unit-testing, maven

I have spring-mvc project.

if click right mouse button on project and make so:

[image]

I see following result:

[image]

if I click so:
[image]

I see next trace(very long):

```
 ...
        **WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Login failed for user 'root'.** ClientConnectionId:f27b5537-3406-4459-9ad5-2d6fa9c57aa4
       ...
     Results :

    Tests in error: 
      getAllCandidatesTest(com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CandidateMenuControllerTest): com.epam.hhsystem.services.CandidateService.getAll()Ljava/util/Set;
      getAllCandidates(com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CandidateMenuControllerTest): com.epam.hhsystem.services.CandidateService.getAll()Ljava/util/Set;        

...
```

What the reason for this behaviour?

**UPDATE**

one of test classes

```
  @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfigUI.xml" })
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class CandidateMenuControllerTest {
...
}
```

BeanConfigUI.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <!-- Включаем опцию использования конфигурационных аннотаций (@Annotation-based 
        configuration) -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.jpa" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.services" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers" />

    <!-- Файл с настройками ресурсов для работы с данными (Data Access Resources) -->
    <import resource="data.xml" />
    <!-- <import resource="security_config.xml" /> -->


     <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

data.xml:
     ...

```
<!-- Настраивает управление транзакциями с помощью аннотации @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Менеджер транзакций -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.16.9.52:1433;databaseName=hhsystemTest;"
        p:username="userNew" 
        p:password="Pass12345" />

    <!-- Настройки фабрики сессий Хибернейта -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:test/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> -->
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

from target-> surefire-reports

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CandidateMenuControllerTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 8, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.813 sec <<< FAILURE!
getAllCandidatesTest(com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CandidateMenuControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 4.849 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.hhsystem.services.CandidateService.getAll()Ljava/util/Set;
    at com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CandidateMenuControllerTest.getAllCandidatesTest(CandidateMenuControllerTest.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
getAllCandidates(com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CandidateMenuControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.089 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.hhsystem.services.CandidateService.getAll()Ljava/util/Set;
    at com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CandidateMenuControllerTest.getAllCandidates(CandidateMenuControllerTest.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at 
...
```

result of `mvn dependency:tree`

```
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI>mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hhsystem ui 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ ui ---
[INFO] com.epam.hhs:ui:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.epam.hhs:core:jar:1.0.9-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-http:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-ssl:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-tcp:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- org.safehaus.jug:jug:jar:asl:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-osgi:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:jar:1.1-osgi:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- asm:asm-commons:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  |  \- asm:asm-tree:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  +- org.jgrapht:jgrapht-jdk1.5:jar:0.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  \- org.mule.common:mule-common:jar:0.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-annotations:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |           \- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3-osgi:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1-osgi:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- tomcat:tomcat-util:jar:5.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- tomcat:tomcat-apr:jar:5.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.samba.jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:7.0.37:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:7.0.37:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:4.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.webjars:jquery-ui:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.webjars:jquery:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.2:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-uberjar-eclipselink:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-jpa-2.0-spec:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-jpa-eclipselink-dependency:pom:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-jpa-default-eclipselink:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-all:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-core:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-connector-1.5-spec:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.util:util-log:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-i18n:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-util:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-api:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-ejb-3.0-spec:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-jpa-1.0-spec:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-ee-deploy-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-jsr77-1.1-spec:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxrpc_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-ee-metadata-common-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- org.ow2.util:util-pool-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-jacc-provider:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jacc_1.1_spec:jar:1.0-M2:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.util:util-ee-deploy-impl:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-archive-impl:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-file:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-xml:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-plan-deploy-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  |  \- org.ow2.util:util-plan-schemas:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  |     \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  |        \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.util.asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.util.asm:asm-commons:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  |  \- org.ow2.util.asm:asm-tree:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- org.ow2.util:util-execution:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.util:util-pool-impl:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- org.ow2.util:util-scan-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.util:util-pool-implenhanced:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- org.ow2.util:util-stream:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-security:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.util:util-xmlconfig:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-transaction:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.apache.tomcat:servlet-api:jar:6.0.13:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-asm:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-asm-commons:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-asm-tree:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.util:util-ee-metadata-ws-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- jotm:jotm:jar:2.0.10:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- jotm:jotm_jrmp_stubs:jar:2.0.10:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- howl:howl-logger:jar:0.1.11:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.carol:carol:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- org.ow2.carol:carol-interceptors:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- commons-modeler:commons-modeler:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.util:util-event-impl:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.ow2.util:util-jmx-impl:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-management:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-jndi-resolver:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-carol:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-cmi:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-jgroups:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-api-client:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  |  \- org.ow2.util:util-component-impl:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-core-common:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-core-server:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  |  \- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-api-server:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-admin:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-cluster-jgroups:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  |  \- jgroups:jgroups:jar:2.6.10.GA:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-jndi:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-rpc:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  |  \- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-ejb2:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  |     \- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-ha:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-core-client:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-lb:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.util:util-event-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-components-event:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |     \- org.ow2.util:util-component-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-deployment:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.util:util-scan-impl:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.ow2.util:util-ee-metadata-ejbjar-impl:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |     +- org.ow2.util:util-ee-metadata-ejbjar-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |     +- org.ow2.util:util-ee-metadata-common-impl:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |     +- org.ow2.util:util-ee-metadata-ws-impl:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |     \- org.ow2.util:util-marshalling:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-hsqldb:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-jdbcpool:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-jca-workmanager:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-joram:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.objectweb.joram:joram-mom:jar:5.3.0:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.objectweb.joram:joram-connector:jar:5.3.0:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.objectweb.joram:joram-client:jar:5.3.0:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.objectweb.joram:joram-shared:jar:5.3.0:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.objectweb.joram:jcup:jar:5.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.objectweb.monolog:monolog:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.objectweb.monolog:monolog-api:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.objectweb.monolog:monolog-core:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-jotm:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-quartz:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.easybeans:quartz:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-mail:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-remotejndiresolver:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-smartclient:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-smartclient-client:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-smartclient-server:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-smartclient-api:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-smartclient-common:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-depmonitor:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.util:util-url:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.ow2.util:util-archive-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-event:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-jmx:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.ow2.util:util-jmx-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-statistic:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-component-audit:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.util:audit-report-api:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.ow2.util:audit-report-impl:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-jpa-openjpa-glue:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-jta-1.1-spec:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-jpa-toplink-essentials-glue:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.ow2.easybeans:easybeans-jpa-eclipselink-glue:jar:1.2.0-M1:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6:runtime (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6:runtime (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:runtime (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.672s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 14 19:36:39 MSK 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/308M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI>
```

**Problems resolved** but doesn't understandable

I have multimodule maven projct
`ui` model depends on `core` module

Initially(then I saw error)

ui-> pom.xml I have not `maven-surefire-plugin`

core->pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

my activities:

- add to core->pom.xml

  `<forkMode>always</forkMode>`

result - doesn't work

- add to ui->pom.xml(see comment unshow here)

  org.apache.maven.plugins
      maven-surefire-plugin
      2.12
          
   always

result - doesn't work

- change core->pom.xml

delete this:

```
<includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
```

**result - good work**

But now if I change something in pom.xml wired with maven-surefire-plugin(I can delete from both pom.xml) it is good work. It is strange for me.

Comment: **WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Login failed for user 'root'.** ClientConnectionId:f27b5537-3406-4459-9ad5-2d6fa9c57aa4 probably

Comment: I see it. I doesn't understand what the root. i use mssql server. I use another user there.

Comment: if I run junit test manually from eclipse - all works good

Comment: [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
can you give us the full trace?
try to mvn install in cmd instead of eclipse.

Comment: How are you storing/loading the database configuration for your tests?

Comment: I cannot post full trace. too long trace

Comment: Jack Leow, I have answered the question?

Comment: <plugin>  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12</version>  
        <configuration>    
 <forkMode>always</forkMode>  
 </configuration> </plugin>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're running all the tests from eclipse and maven (9 in total), this is important to ensure that you don't have unexpected interactions between your tests, and one test leaves something in an inconsistent state.

Now, if the assumption above is correct, then one following might apply (these comes from my experience).

1) The usual culprit is that eclipse doesn't use the exact same classpath as maven, and this sometimes causes errors in eclipse, or hides errors in maven.

Usually the problem is that there are incompatible versions of the same jar in the class path (as a very generic example spring-core 3.0.1.RELEASE and spring-beans 3.2.4.RELEASE).

One easiest way to fix this is to use the [TattleTale plugin](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) to report which classes are duplicated in your classpath.
The more difficult approach is to run `mvn dependency:tree` and scan if you have any duplicated libraries (even libraries that changed the group/artefact id recently... such as Spring).

2) Another option is to change the fork mode in the surefire plugin (the default changed quite recently), and set it to `forkMode=always` ([docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html)), as newer versions of the plugin reuse the forks.

Comment: I have updated my topic. Maybe you can see the cause of my mistake

Comment: It's one of the cases I mentioned, eclipse is using a different classpath and that's why you're getting `NoSuchMethodError com.epam.hhsystem.services.CandidateService.getAll` if this is a multi module project be sure that you have the cross dependencies between the modules in maven. About the database error, you have a problem in your DB connection string, and your app cannot connect to the DB.

Comment: it is multi module project. ui module(invoke tests for this) and ui depends on core.

Comment: I have all problems ONLY from maven

Comment: I haven't problems with database connection if I run unit tests

Comment: You have to think the oposite way, the problem is **not** maven, but Eclipse, as it messes up the classloader and gives you the impression that everything is ok when it's not. You also have 2 versions of spring (3.2.3 and 3.0.7) and 2 versions of aspectj (1.7 and 1.6). Can you sort the dependencies out and report what you find?

Comment: Well maybe it is Maven. As you execute your tests with forkMode, maybe you should try to disable it with forkMode=none (I think this parameter has changed in the last version of surefire). By executing these tests simultanously in maven, you can have a different behaviour (than executing singlely in Eclipse).

Comment: your answer is not concrete, but I got information which helps me.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem was in not rebuilt core module - eclipse don't use jar from maven repo if project with needed groupId/artifactId/version exists in workspace - it rebuild it as needed but don't install to maven repo.

When you run mvn install on ui module it uses jar for core from maven repo, where old version of module was installed.

After rebuild of core module all stated work fine, because maven repo now contains correct library (with new added methods)

Comment: Я не совсем понял( может по русски для меня напишите?

Comment: Мавен использует при запуске джарники из репозитория `~/.m2/repository`. Эклипс, если находит зависимый модуль в воркспейсе - автоматически перед запуском тестов его перекомпилит и при запуске тестов будет использвать его. Если вы изменили код модуля и не сделали `install` на зависимом модуле, то мавен и эклипс будут использовать разные версии библиотеки (поле version одно, но по факту там разный код) - эклипс из воркспейса, мавен - из локального репозитория. Судя по ошибкам типа "не найден метод" вы добавили метод в исходниках, а в репозитории класс без этого метода.

Comment: спасибо, буду знать это.